# Deezer Artists TOP songs method, same token, different answers

Tags: deezer

This call

```
http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/4762/top?output=xml&limit=30&access_token=...
```

executed via server gives me two different lists of songs if it is executed from a USA server OR from a Spanish server.

I have been told that, using a PREMIUM token, the API should answer according to the country of the user, but in this case it doesn't happen (the token belongs to the same premium user).

These are the songs (id) I get from US:

1016021
74440163
74254892
72545071
1016005
74254893
74254895
73945040
1016003
74254894
73945037
74254896
73945038
64820753
73945039
73945045
64820745
16880921
73945041
64820747
73945042
64820750
1016023
73945043
73945046
73945044
64820746
7511353
73945047
64820755

these are the ones I get from spain

74440163
74254892
73945036
74254893
73945040
74254895
74254894
73945037
73945038
74254896
73945039
64820753
73945045
64820745
64820756
73945041
16880921
64820747
73945042
64820750
73945043
73945044
73945046
64820746
7511353
73945047
64820755
64820748
64820757
16881228

Also strange is that if, from the US server, I try to get info about the first song retrieved

```
http://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/1016021/?access_token=...
```

The API says that the song is not readable; can a "not-readable" song be in the top 30?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your account should be Premium+ to get still the same content regardless of your location.

Comment: I said Premium but it is actually premium+